# openMP file IO, missing some records

Tags: c++, io, parallel-processing, openmp, file-handling

I have the following openMP code in c++, basically it creates a string for each user and and writes it to a file (I do not care about the order). What happens is that I am missing some records (3K out of 2M). Does anyone know what might be the cause and how to fix it? (My suspicion is one thread terminated first and close the file?) Thanks!!

```
#pragma omp parallel for 
    for(int m = 1; m <= uid[0]; m++){
            double val[ARRAY_SIZE]={0.};
            int top[ARRAY_SIZE]={0};
            for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
                    double pred_v = 0;
                    for(int t = 0; t < rank; t++){
                            pred_v += W[uid[m]-1][t] * H[i-1][t];
                    }
                    double min = val[0];
                    int min_idx = 0;
                    for(int j = 1; j < k; j++){
                            if(val[j] < min){
                                    min = val[j];
                                    min_idx = j;
                            }
                    }
                    if(min<pred_v){
                            val[min_idx] = pred_v;
                            top[min_idx] = i;
                    }
            }
            stringstream buf;
            buf << uid[m];
            for(int j = 0; j < k; j++)
                    buf << "\t" << top[j] << ":" << val[j];
            buf << "\n";
            #pragma omp critical
            fprintf(output_fp, buf.str().c_str()); //I think there is some problem here
    }
```

Comment: You don't close the file within the `#pragma`, it looks like. OpenMP is supposed to synchronize at the end of a `#pragma omp parallel for` block, so even if one thread finished first, it shouldn't go on and close the file until everyone else has caught up. Where do you close the file? Is it immediately after the loop, or is there anything else in between?

Comment: Yes, immediate after the loop. I did something like `fclose(output_fp);`